# itext - How to add a shape right before a line of text?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I want to add a colored rectangle object right before a specific `Paragraph` object.

Essentially, I want to convert this CSS code to itext:

```
#theText li:before {
    content: "■";
    color: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    left: -5px;
}
```

Color, font-size, and alignment I know how to do in itext, but how do I position the rectangle right before a line of text? The [`Rectangle`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/Rectangle.html) class accepts absolute coordinates for the position of the rectangle object, but this is impractical, so is there a way to give like an ID to the paragraph object, and position the rectangle relative to it?

I am using itext 5.5.9.